# Netbeans GUI and dealing with Threads inside "main"

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, netbeans

I'm using *Netbeans* IDE to make a GUI. The point is that when I add a *JFrame* frame to my project package:

[image: Creating new Jframe]

it declares every variable of the frame (button, textArea, ..etc) as private and can't change it. the problem comes when I'm trying to create thread that uses these variables in `run()` method inside `main` method.

> note: I've tried to create separate class extends Thread, I can't call it in the `main` unless I declare it as `static`, then same problem rises again.

how can I make thread that uses these variables (i.e. appending text to text area) inside the `main` ?

Comment: Outside classes shouldn't be directly manipulating fields of a class as that increases code coupling and increases risk of side effects and difficult to find bugs. Instead give your class public methods to allow outside classes to change state -- but under the control of the class itself, such as getter/setter methods for the most simple example of this, and then other classes can call these methods as needed.

Comment: If you really, really, really are 100% sure that you really, really need to access those variables: create getter and setter for them. But as others have said you should **not** _change_ components outside the EDT.

Answer (score 4):

Do not try to do that. UI elements shall **not** be accessed from another thread than the Event Dispatch Thread. You will find references on Oracle Java tutorial [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/). Extracts (emphasize mine) :

A Swing programmer deals with the following kinds of threads:

- Initial threads, the threads that execute initial application code.
- The event dispatch thread, where all event-handling code is executed. **Most code that interacts with the Swing framework must also execute on this thread.**
- Worker threads, also known as background threads, where time-consuming background tasks are executed.

Some Swing component methods are labelled "thread safe" in the API specification; these can be safely invoked from any thread. **All other Swing component methods must be invoked from the event dispatch thread**. Programs that ignore this rule may function correctly most of the time, but are subject to unpredictable errors that are difficult to reproduce.